# swift raise unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I am using 3rd party external framework in my **objective-c** project. I created an **swift** file in this project to use the framework.

In **MyModule-Bridging-Header.h** I have import external framework header

```
#import “ext-service/ext-service.h”
```

In the **ext-service.h** there is an constant:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, service_err_t) {
    SERVICE_SUCCESS = 1
}
```

In my **swift** code

```
//Compiler error: use of unresolved identifier ‘SERVICE_SUCCESS’
if result == SERVICE_SUCCESS{
     NSLog(“successful!”)
}
```

But I get compiler error:

```
use of unresolved identifier ‘SERVICE_SUCCESS’
```

Why?

Comment: Have you tried `service_err_t.SERVICE_SUCCESS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason to the error you mentioned is `SERVICE_SUCESS` is unavailable(unknown).

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Use `service_err_t.SERVICE_SUCCESS` instead of `SERVICE_SUCESS`
2. `result` is of type `service_err_t` then just using `.SERVICE_SUCESS`

Hope this helps!